# ParseExection error in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am getting an error when executing a select statement in Hive.

Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:33 cannot recognize input near '' '' ''

Query Sample: ;with cte1 as ( select * from table1)
, cte2 as ( select * from table2)
, cte3 as (select * from table3)
select * from cte2 
join cte3 on cte2.col1 = cte3.col1
join cte1 on cte1.col1 = cte2.col1;

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the alias reference, add the keywound "as" after your alias like

```
with cte1 as  ( select * from table1) , cte2 as ( select * from table2) , cte3 as ( select * from table3) select * from cte2 join cte3 on cte2.col1 = cte3.col1 join cte1 on cte1.col1 = cte2.col1
```

Tested in hive 1.1

Comment: i missed 'as'  in my question, but i used it in my query.

Comment: from where are you running this? beeline, hive, jdbc, hue? can you print exactly your query and split it in different lines? I dont see any " character.

Comment: i am not supposed to share my code, that is the reason i gave template and i didnt miss any ... i am executing it in Ambari Hive 2.0.